# Curl how to use cookies

Tags: php, cookies, curl, setcookie

Hey i am trying to use cookies in curl, but I can not get it to work so basically what I need is to when loading the url set cookie with `ab = 1 ab2 = 3 and ab3 = 10`, I tried loading cookies but that doesnt work then i tried this code

```
curl_setopt($curl,array('Cookie: ab=1,ab2=3,ab3=10'));
```

but I am getting errors.

Comment: saying your getting errors, but not telling us what the errors are is pointless.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `curl_setopt` wrong, and the format of your cookie isn't quite right.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'ab=1; ab2=3; ab3=10');
```

Comment: Also, just for completeness, the HTTP header is called `Set-Cookie`, not `Cookie`.

Comment: @Jonhoo: curl is client, not server, see as well http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Requests

Comment: @Jonhoo that's not quite right - `Set-Cookie` is the response header sent from the server to the client to set a cookie. `Cookie` is a request header (from the client to the server) reporting a cookie.

Comment: No worries James. If you're happy, can you mark it as the answer by clicking the tick to the left? Thanks, and welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 2):

You're calling [`curl_set_opt`<sup>*PHP Manual*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) wrong. Your version is for setting a single option. If you want to pass an `array` of options, then you have to use [`curl_setopt_array`<sup>*PHP Manual*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt-array.php).

Try:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "ab=1, ab2=3, ab3=10")
```

Comment: The cookies should be separated with a semi-colon followed by a space, not a comma

Comment: Not up to me to decide how the OP wants his cookie formatted. it could be a single `ab` cookie with a value of `1,ab2=3,ab3=10`.